# access json fields after $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using following js script which loads custom geojson file depending on time parameter passed(date format):

```
_getDataForTime: function(time) {
    if (!this._map) {
        return;
    }
    var jsd ={}
    var d = new Date(time);
    url0="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/"
    var url = url0+ d.format("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH", true) + '.geojson';
    var callback = function(status, data) {        
        console.log(status);
        jsd=data;
        console.log(data);
        // data
        if (status == 'ok'){
            
            this._currentTimeData = data;

        } else{
            this._currentTimeData = [];
        }
        this._currentLoadedTime = time;
        if (this._timeDimension && time == this._timeDimension.getCurrentTime() && !this._timeDimension.isLoading()) {
            this._update();
        }
        this.fire('timeload', {
            time: time
        });
    };
    
    $.getJSON(url, callback.bind(this, 'ok')).fail(callback.bind(this, 'error'));

}
```

[Here is example of geojson file used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tekija/LCd/master/2020-01-01T21.geojson) - can be used instead of `url` variable.

I can log data to console with `console.log(data)`, but I cant access individual fields in JSON i.e. `t2m` and `coordinates`.

How can I do this?
I tried referencing with `data.features.t2m` but no success.

Comment: data.features is an Array...data.features[0].t2m?

Comment: `features` is an array. Each object in that array has the properties you want but they are also nested inside other properties